# How to detect whether the Dart code is running in pure-Dart environment or running inside Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have some `Dart` code, and inside that code, I want to know whether it is running as pure Dart or running inside the Flutter environment. How do achieve this?

I guess this should be very simple, but interestingly a search does not reveal any solutions...

Comment: By what criteria do you consider a Flutter environment to not be a pure Dart environment?

Comment: Or perhaps your question really is "How can Dart code detect if it's used in a Flutter application?" But then that raises the question: Why do you care?  [What problem are you actually trying to solve?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @jamesdlin Hi thanks for the reply. I have some Rust code that is called by Dart/Flutter. Thus I need to detect the environment in order to know whether to load a separate `.dylib` file or use the current-process binary.